# Need help in generating access token for Checkmarx API

Tags: api, rest, checkmarx

I would be working on a POC to get checkmarx reports using REST API, for this I have reffered checkmarx API knowledge documentation and it looks like we need an access token to interact with checkmarx API using Java REST API.

Can someone please help me on how to generate Access token for Checkmarx API.

Thanks,
Karthik P.

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the [documentation](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/1187774721/Using+the+CxSAST+REST+API+v8.6.0+and+up)

Basically, you need to send POST request to `/cxrestapi/auth/identity/connect/token` endpoint with bunch of hardcoded values:

```
'grant_type': 'password',
'scope': 'sast_rest_api',
'client_id': 'resource_owner_client',
'client_secret': '014DF517-39D1-4453-B7B3-9930C563627C',
```

And your credentials:

```
'username': 'INSERT_USERNAME',
'password': 'INSERT_PASS',
```

If everything is OK, you'll get JSON response with `access_token` key which is your token, to be used in following requests as header like `Authorization: Bearer <INSERT_TOKEN>`